# DataTables append con AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

Necesito agregar un resultado obtenido mediante AJAX a una tabla, pero no logro que la respuesta se muestre de forma correcta.
De hecho, lo que sucede es que cada vez que se muestra la tabla, se agrega nuevamente el resultado.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   
var tableSucursal =  $('#SucursalesTabla').DataTable(
  {
    responsive: true,
 rowReorder: true,
 "scrollX": true 
});


tableSucursal.rows().every( function () {
 
    this.child( '<table id="InternosTabla" width="100%"><thead><tr><th  class="id">Apellido</th><th>Nombre</th><th>Cargo</th><th>Tel&eacute;fono</th><th>M&oacute;vil</th><th colspan="2">E-mail</th><th>Observaciones</th><th align="center"><a id="AgregarInternos" style="cursor:pointer; display:none;" onclick="AgregarInternos();">Nuevo</a></tr></th>'+
 '</thead>'+
 '<tbody>'+

 '</tbody>'+
 '</table>' 
 );
 

 
});

function datos(sucursal) {

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "clientes_showint.php",
  data: {sucursal:sucursal},
  success: function(data){
 $("#InternosTabla tbody").append(data);
  }
  });
}


$('#SucursalesTabla tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
 var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = tableSucursal.row( tr );

    var child = tableSucursal.row(this).child;
 var sucursal=$(this).closest("tr").find(".id").text(); 

 
    if (row.child.isShown()) {
        row.child.hide();
    }
    else {
    row.child.show();
 row.child(datos(sucursal)).show();
    }
});
```

El llamado de AJAX devuelve

```
<tr class="Internos"><td></td><td id="idintaut53" class="idinterno" style="display:none;" data-campo="id_intaut">53</td><td id="intaut" class="" data-campo="apellido"><span>590005</span></td><td id="intaut" class="" data-campo="nombres"><span></span></td><td id="intaut" class="" data-campo="cargo"><span></span></td><td id="intaut" class="" data-campo="telfijo"><span></span></td><td id="intaut" class="" data-campo="telmovil"><span></span></td><td id="intaut" class="" data-campo="email" colspan="2"><span></span></td><td id="intaut" class="" data-campo="observaciones"><span></span></td><td id="intaut" class="" data-campo="ActivoNoActivo" align="center"><span class="label label-success">&nbsp;</span></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

datatable js ya tiene función para cargar

```
tableSucursal.clear().rows.add(data).draw();
```

donde:

- [dt.clear()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear()) limpia la tabla
- [dt.rows.add(lst](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html)) agrega nueva data
- [dt.draw()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) lo muestra en pantalla

Comment: Gracias! Está muy bien, pero no me agrega nada a la tabla. 
Agrego al post lo que me devuelve el AJAX. 
Es posible que sea por eso?